# How to add path aliases for images in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsconfig

I have configured `paths` in `tsconfig.json`. Everything works fine except importing asset files like `svg` and `png`.

Here is my `paths` in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@components": ["./src/components"],
      "@app/*": ["./src/app/*"],
      "static": ["static/*"]
    },
    ...
}
```

Here how I import:

```
import imageAdd from "static/images/image-add.png";
import circleIcon from "static/icons/circle-close.svg"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, solved. Need to add some `d.ts` file. Eg. `images.d.ts` with content:

```
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.jpg";
```

After go to `tsconfig.json` file and add this file to `include`:

```
  "include": ["images.d.ts", <other includes>]
```

Probably, you'll need to install `file-loader`. I use gatsby, so I didn't need to configure anything

Answer (score 2):

Replace `"static": ["static/*"]` with `"static/*": ["static/*"]`

Comment: I have tried it already. Doesn't work. But thanks for an answer!

Comment: You may also need to have your bundler (webpack, rollup) configured for that to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, webpack also configured and still doesn't work